# How to triangulate mixed surface mesh (obtained from `GraphicsComplex`)

Tags: mesh, meshrefinementfunction

Examplary `ContourPlot3D`

```
pic = ContourPlot3D[x^3 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

provides a `GraphicsComplex` which includes the meshed surface!

```
pts = pic[[1, 1]][[1]]; 
poly = Cases[pic, Polygon[p_] :> p, -1];
```

`poly` consists of polygons with 3,4,5,6 elements which are plotted separately

```
GraphicsRow@Table[Graphics3D[Map[Polygon[pts[[#]]] &, poly[[k]]]], {k, 1,Length[poly]}]
```

[image]

My question:
Is there a simple way to triangulate this mixed surface mesh?

Thanks!

Comment: does `DiscretizeGraphics@pic` give what you need?

Comment: or `dg = DiscretizeGraphics@pic;
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@dg, MeshCells[dg, 2]]]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks! Is there an option in `DiscretizeGraphics` to force triangular mesh?

Comment: I don't know if there is an option; but maybe we can use `TriangulateMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[pic]]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks again for yor helpful answers!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You can hit the result of `DiscretizeGraphics` with ``Region`Mesh`TriangulateMeshCells``. Also `DiscretizeRegion` seems to yield a triangular mesh too.

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks! What is th correct syntax to apply "Region`Mesh`TriangulateMeshCells" ?

Comment: I think you just pass in a `MeshRegion` object. And then there are options to control the triangulation size quality, etc.

Comment: @GregHurst Thanks again! My problem is `MeshRegion[pts, Polygon@Flatten[poly, 1]]` doesn't evaluate and give an error "Polygon... not coplanar". That's why I can't pass MeshRegion and test yor function.

Comment: This works for me: ``Region`Mesh`TriangulateMeshCells[DiscretizeGraphics[pic]]``

Comment: In fact It looks like `DiscretizeGraphics` is triangulating this already: `In[4]:= DiscretizeGraphics[pic]["MeshCellTypes"]

Out[4]= {{{Polygon, {1884, 3}}}}`